# META-INF (Is a directory) on extracting jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have created a jar file with Maven [1] that in the end it creates a jar file named `medusa-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. When I try to extract the content of the file, I get this error [2]. Why I get this error? Is this a problem in the `pom.xml`?

[1] Maven configuration

```
 <plugin>
            <!-- create one fat jar -->
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>
                        jar-with-dependencies
                    </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.jar.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/examples/Teste.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.ExampleDriver</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

[2] error when extracting the jar file

```
$ jar xf medusa-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF (Is a directory)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
   at sun.tools.jar.Main.copy(Main.java:909)
   at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:1069)
   at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:981)
   at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:311)
   at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

Comment: The `META-INF` directory might be the very first entry in the .jar file, so the `FileNotFoundException` might be a misnomer for you not being authorized to create a directory in the current directory.

Comment: Which version of maven-assembly-plugin do you use?

Comment: I am using Apache Maven 3.0.5. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: And the version of assembly plugin is 2.5.5

Comment: Maybe should I use One-Jar plugin instead of the maven assembly.

Comment: Does anyone know another plugin to create a fat jar beside one-jar and maven assembly plugin?

Comment: Just one more thing, I am doing this because I want to launch an hadoop job in a jar file with classpath. E.g., `hadoop jar  medusa-java-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Maybe there is a way to set the classpath in hadoop, but I haven't found also.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I would really like to know why this is happening. Nothing is able to unzip my fat jar.

Comment: I have same problem. `jar tf` command displays that `META-INF` is created as an *empty file*, not as a *directory*. Workaround: Use `unzip` command to extract it, and skip all error files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Since I want to use MapReduce I should not build a fat jar with all the dependencies inside, but I should put the jars in the $HADOOP_MAPREDUCE libs dir. I did it, and it worked.

This [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) helped me.